# I am unable to add hr which extends to the whole line below a div

Tags: css, html

here is my code, I want to separate 2 divs by adding an hr in between, can anyone help me to add a hr which will extend to the whole line below intro and intro image, as the hr is only extended till intro image, so can anyone help me out with the hr-

```
#intro{
         font-family: 'Sansita', sans-serif; 
        font-size: 170%;    
        float: right;                   
        width: 50%;                
        margin-right: 20px;
         margin-left: 10px;
            color: #ff471a ;
        } 



        #introImage { 

            float: left;
            width: 40%;
            margin-left: 70px;
            margin-top: 35px;
            box-shadow: 10px 10px grey;
            border-radius: 10px;

        }




    #hitchhiking-info {

        margin-top: 20px;
        width: 100%; 
        height: 100px;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: blue;
        float: none;

    }
```

```
    <div id="intro-div"> 

        <p id="intro"> Hello There! I have made this website to share my experiences of hitchhiking, which is my full time job. I want to inspire other hitchhikers as well and inspire people. This website will hopefully clear all your misconceptions about hitchhiking as a proffession, as it is underrated and critisized by people. However I have a very different perspective about hitchhiking, you will get to know about it through my website. This website is a mean I will be using to reach to people around the world. Fell free to comment any suggestions or feedback of my experiences and contact me for any query </p>    

        <img id="introImage" src="intro-image.jpg">




    </div> 

    <div id="hitchhiking-info">

        <h1 id="heading"> Hitchhiking </h1>   
    </div>
```

[image: This is the layout of my page]

Comment: post the screenshot of the current design

Comment: Out of context: note the typo in your text: 'Fell free to...". It must be "Feel free to..." (last sentence.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important thing is to add this:

```
#intro-div {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Any container which only contains floated elements will have 0 height. To avoid this, you have to add `overflow: auto;` or `overflow: hidden` to its CSS.

See the result here:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MJzdda

Answer (score 1):

[image][image]
    [image]

**JUST ADDED `<hr/>` and it works**

```
<div id="intro-div"> 

        <p id="intro">  However I have a very different perspective about hitchhiking, you will get to know about it through my website. This website is a mean I will be using to reach to people around the world. Fell free to comment any suggestions or feedback of my experiences and contact me for any query </p>    

        <img id="introImage" src="intro-image.jpg">


<hr/>

    </div> 

    <div id="hitchhiking-info">

        <h1 id="heading"> Hitchhiking </h1>   
    </div>


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbY63.png
```

Comment: actually I am a student, and I was assigned a problem to create a website for hitchhiking, so to me honest, I don't know much about it.

Comment: hr { margin-left: -8px; } add this in css now it will look like this

Comment: I have aligned the element in a very different way, kindly see the css of it

Comment: @PiyushMaheshwari Could you show how your design looks

Answer (score 0):

Add the hr tag between your div's and then in your css file, play with the css of the hr tag

```
hr { 
display: block;
margin-top: 0.5em;
margin-bottom: 0.5em;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
border-style: inset;
border-width: 1px;
}
```

Play with the margin-right and margin-left properties to adjust the length of the line.